# Login to Sharepoint Web Application Fails?

Tags: sharepoint

I've installed Sharepoint (standard version) on a local server. This server runs on Windows 2008. I've created a Web application intranet.sharepoint.com
I changed my host file, so that it directs to this local server.

However when I run the web Application, I'm getting a login screen and I cannot login! Do I need to activate something after creating the Web Application?

Can somebody help me with this?

Regards,

G. Jerry

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried sorting the loopback in iis?
http://koenvosters.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/access-denied-when-using-hostname-search-and-site-on-moss-2007/

Answer (score 1):

- Open regedit
- go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
- Open or create the multistring value BackConnectionHostNames
- Add application intranet.sharepoint.com

More infos:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887993/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the Site Collection under the Web Application ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a login screen that does not do anything is caused by a SQL connection problem. Try logging in with FireFox instead of IE. That may cause the error message to be sent to the browser.